# Intercept paste event inside a variable in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to intecept a paste event inside a webpage (it doesn't matter where I paste, i need to intercept also outside an input field so I set BODY for the event)

This is a code found somewhere here. I modified it to put the pasted content inside a variable `c` for other purposes, but i don't know how, it result always empty.

How can I fix this? Or... is there a jquery plugin better compatibles with ALL browsers?

```js
$('body').on('paste', function(e) {
  var c = "";
  var dt = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;

  if (dt && dt.items && dt.items[0]) {
    dt.items[0].getAsString(function(text) {
      $('.log').text(text);
      c = text;
    });
  } else {
    if (dt && ('getData' in dt)) {
      $('.log').text(dt.getData('text'));
      c = dt.getData('text');
    }
  }

  console.log(c); //<-- always empty

  // do some stuff with my "c" variable
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Pasted text: <span class="log"></span>
</p>
```

Script: http://jsfiddle.net/6n10y0ds/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because `getAsString()` is asynchronous, therefore you're attempting to read `c` before the value has been set.

To fix this extract the logic dependant on `c` in to its own function and call that function in the callback of `getAsString()`:

```js
$('body').on('paste', function(e) {
  var c = "";
  var dt = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;

  if (dt && dt.items && dt.items[0]) {
    dt.items[0].getAsString(function(text) {
      $('.log').text(text);
      doStuff(text);
    });
  } else {
    if (dt && ('getData' in dt)) {
      $('.log').text(dt.getData('text'));
      doStuff(dt.getData('text'));
    }
  }
});

function doStuff(foo) {
  console.log('You pasted', foo);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  Pasted text: <span class="log"></span>
</p>
```